# Can the IO streams of Apache 2.x be intercepted? (especially curious about mod_wsgi)

Tags: apache-http-server, debug, mod-wsgi

Just trying out ideas useful for future debugging adventures.

I thought that it would be useful to take a look directly at at what goes on between the server and mod_wsgi.

So anyone aware if I can intercept (and perhaps log/ modify at runtime/ overwrite) the data sent/ received through stdin, stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Tracking_Request_and_Response

If that isn't sufficient, it isn't obvious what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanations, it all makes more sense now.